# How to change the wallpaper for all spaces in macOS using Applescript/shell?

Tags: macos, shell, automation, applescript

Before I've written this question, I've reviewed several answers and the most popular ones was

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell every desktop
        set picture to "/Users/xyz/Documents/Screenshots/wallpaper.png"
    end tell
end tell
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.

What I've tried?
Steps:

1. Make sure have more than one space
2. Run the script

Expected result: All spaces should see new wallpaper
Actual result: Wallpaper is changed to only current space

Goal: Is there a way to change the wallpaper to all the spaces using applescript/shell?

Comment: The script above changes desktop picture for multiple **displays**, but not desktop picture of user **workspaces**, created by Mission Control.app. To change picture of user workspaces created by Mission Control.app you can save this script as application (for example, on the desktop, or set Keep in Dock for its icon). Then, after manually swittching the workspace, you can run this app (clicking on its icon) for every workspace separatelly. I think, you can't automate this process using applescript/shell, because Mission Control.app is not scriptable.

Comment: yeah it is some I figured but somehow app like Cleanshot able to make it work. Not sure how they are able to do it.